# Passing the Model to the View in MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I've always understood MVC to mean the Model shouldn't know anything about the View and vice versa. However in my university course an example of a View using the MVC pattern is given like:

```
class View implements Updatable {

    private final JButton button = new JButton("Press Me!");
    private final JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);

    //some setup of the button and textfield

    public void update(Model model) {
        if (model.morePressesAllowed()) {
            textField.setText(String.valueOf(model.count()));
        } else {
            textField.setText("Too Many!");
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems odd to me that the view must know what methods the model has. It seems like it would be better in terms of the MVC pattern to expose the button and textfield to the controller, and have the update method on the controller?

The model just increments a number and if it gets to 5 then the morePressesAllowed returns false.

Also the model has a list of Updatable, and when the counter changes it loops through the updatables  and calls update, while this is better than having a list Views, it still seems like the Controller should be responsible for telling the view when the model changes?

EDIT: The model is:

```
class Model {
    private final List<Updatable> views = new ArrayList<Updatable>();
    private int count;
    private boolean morePressesAllowed = true;
    public void addObserver(Updatable observer) {
        views.add(observer);
    }
    public void increment() {
        count++;
        if (count >= 5) {
            morePressesAllowed = false;
        }
        notifyObservers();
    }
    private void notifyObservers() {
        for (Updatable view : views) {
            view.update(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The Controller/Main class: (also shouldn't the controller create the model and view and be normal public class?)

```
public class GuiApp {
    private View view = new View(new Controller());
    private Model pressCounter = new Model();

    class Controller implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            pressCounter.increment();
        }
    }
    GuiApp() {
        pressCounter.addObserver(view);
    }
}
```

Also I actually prefer this to something like this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm Because in that the controller is just wrapping a bunch of methods of the view and model, which while it seems more MVC like in that the Model and View don't know anything about each other, it just seems less efficient and more complex?

Comment: Can you also show the model?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like it would be better in terms of the MVC pattern to expose the button and textfield to the controller, and have the update method on the controller?

This would create a coupling between the view and the controller. It is important that each layer knows as little about one another as possible. You don't want a controller that is dependant on the existence of some text boxes or buttons. You want the controller to pass the data back to the view, and not care what happens to it beyond then. That is the job of the view. That is the whole point of delegation.

> Also the model has a list of Updatable, and when the counter changes it loops through the updatables and calls update, while this is better than having a list Views, it still seems like the Controller should be responsible for telling the view when the model changes?

You're correct. It is not the role of the view to call a method on the Model. Again, this creates an undesirable coupling.

> also shouldn't the controller create the model and view and be normal public class?

Yes. More often than not, I see the controller *communicate* with the model layer, or some service, that then returns the models that are then delegated to the view.

> Because in that the controller is just wrapping a bunch of methods of the view and model, which while it seems more MVC like in that the Model and View don't know anything about each other, it just seems less efficient and more complex?

These methods are known as *Proxy Methods*. Methods that simply delegate the call to something else. It's helpful when you're trying to maintain an appropriate *separation of concerns* in your architecture. It depends on your definition of complex. Yes, it adds more methods to your controller. Then again, when the next developer comes along, if he or she can make the assumption, safely, that your application strictly follows an MVC architecture, they will have a much easier time developing against your code, as opposed to having to work out your micro-optimisations and "work arounds".

Comment: "You're correct. It is not the role of the view to call a method on the Model. Again, this creates an undesirable coupling." At the moment it is the model calling a method on the view (although it doesn't know it's a view, all it knows it's updatable)

Comment: "You want the controller to pass the data back to the view" So pass just the relevant data and not the model? While this would mean it's less coupled, if I change the model to output another piece of data, I then have to change the controller to pass the new data to the view and change the view to receive the data from the controller. Whereas now with the model being passed to the view although it's more coupled, if the model changes then the controller doesn't need to be.